# mySwiper is not defined with jquery and cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I work with cordova and jquery, and i try to use Swiper by idangero.

I tried to do this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //initialize swiper when document ready
    var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
    // Optional parameters
    autoplay: ‘3000’,
    loop: true
    })
});
```

but when i call it in this part:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', ‘#listDetail’, function(){
    … some codes …
    if(row.pictures != ''){
        var numslide = mySwiper.slides.length;
        mySwiper.appendSlide(slidecontent);
        for (var i = 0; i < numslide; i++) {
            mySwiper.removeSlide(0);
        }
        mySwiper.updateSlidesSize();
    }else{
        mySwiper.removeAllSlides();
    }
    … some codes …
});
```

i have this **Uncaught ReferenceError: mySwiper is not defined** message.

Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define `mySwiper` before initializing it so it can be used outside of the `$(document).ready` function scope

```
var mySwiper;
$(document).ready(function () {
    //initialize swiper when document ready
    mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
        // Optional parameters
        autoplay: ‘3000’,
        loop: true
    })
});
```

Alternatively, you could get the Swiper instance in your other event like this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', ‘#listDetail’, function(){
    … some codes …
    if(row.pictures != ''){
        var mySwiper = $('.swiper-container')[0].swiper;
        var numslide = mySwiper.slides.length;
        mySwiper.appendSlide(slidecontent);
        for (var i = 0; i < numslide; i++) {
            mySwiper.removeSlide(0);
        }
        mySwiper.updateSlidesSize();
    }else{
        mySwiper.removeAllSlides();
    }
    … some codes …
});
```